# Responsive layout without CSS3

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design

I'm wondering if is possible to have a responsive layout without using CSS3. Are there other techniques that allow us to accomplish the same results?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by responsive. Can you please clarify? (in my ears, its when an application feels fast; cannot see a context to CSS here, except that CSS3 might be slower due to more effects etc.)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_Web_Design

Comment: Excuse my ignorance please. Seems for me though that this is not possible (media queries not being available in css2 etc.). Javascript could help with browser and display size identification though, but I'm out of discussion here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to take a look Respond.js: https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond

It is meant as a polyfill for browsers that don't support Media Queries. I'm not sure why you would need to avoid using them all together in browsers that support them, but this should do the trick.

Comment: I'm not avoid them, I just want to explore other possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you set all your widths in percentages, the page will be fluid. Start with something like:

```
body{ margin:0 auto; width:94%; padding:0 3%; max-width:1024px; }
```